# Let's say I have manufactured a prism from a non-dispersive medium, then light coming from air wouldn't split into colours right?

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction, frequency, dispersion

Let's say I have manufactured a prism from a non-dispersive medium, then light coming from air incident on the prism wouldn't split into colours, right? I mean light still changes direction, but all colours would change direction by the same amount.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Unless you consider that air is slightly dispersive. But usually we approximate air as free space $n=1$. So in that approximation yes the prism wouldn't split light into different colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this hypothetical question, you're correct if the index of refraction does not change as a function of wavelength of light, then the angle of refraction for all the wavelengths will be the same for all wavelengths and hence no dispersion.

However, the Kramers-Kronig relation requires that there be some dispersion.